# How to display data in my JSON array as separate lines using handlebars

Tags: json, handlebars.js

Im having trouble getting my json array from my database to display each sentence in the array on a new line. 
[Json code in MongoDB database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPaBn.png)

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5a9546659f96044402c2403a"),
"title" : "Asthma",
"description" : [ 
    "1. Help the person sit in a comfortable position and help them take their medicine.", 
    "2. Reassure the person.", 
    "3. If the attack becomes severe, they dont have their medication or they dont improve call the emergency services."
],
"image" : "https://danu7.it.nuigalway.ie:8710/images/asthma.jpg"
```

}

I have looked up ways to do this and tried some out to no avail. I want the sentences to print out at follows.

1. ---
2. ---
3. ---

Currently this is what my code looks like [handlebar file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nccml.png)

```
  {{#each tutorials}}
<center>
<img src={{image}}>
<br>{{description}}
</center>
{{/each}}
```

and this is how it is displaying on my webpage [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFIjW.png)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

For me it looks like you're printing the whole `description` array at once.

So improve the line `<br>{{description}}` to `<br>{{#each description}}{{this}}<br>{{/each}}` and all description elements will be printed in a new line.

Comment: Hi thanks for commenting.. I tried this but when I load my page now nothing will display. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Can you create a [JSfildde](https://jsfiddle.com) with the snippet of the example code? That would be great, so I'm able to debug your little problem. :)